# Moving SKSpriteNode over screen

Tags: swift, touch, skspritenode, touchesbegan, touchesmoved

I want to move an SKSpriteNode over the screen with touch. The issue I have is that if I lock onto one sprite and then my finger drags it over another sprite the first one is let go and my finger starts to drag the second one. But once I touch the first sprite this is the only one I want to move.
There must be a simple way to resolve this?

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */
    let touch: UITouch = touches.first as UITouch!
    touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch: UITouch = touches.first as UITouch!
    let newTouchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
    let targetNode = self.nodeAtPoint(touchLocation)
    if targetNode.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask != PhysicsCategory.Ball {
    targetNode.runAction(SKAction.moveBy(CGVector(point: newTouchLocation - touchLocation), duration: 0.0))
    touchLocation = newTouchLocation
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    //I don't do anything with this yet
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because your touchesMoved function is running every time your finger moves and if your finger moves over a new node, that node will be assigned to targetNode. You can fix this by changing this line:

```
let targetNode = self.nodeAtPoint(touchLocation)
```

To this:

```
let targetNode = self.nodeAtPoint(touch)
```

This way the node at the first touch will be the one that follows your finger and not the one at the last touch.

Comment: It does not work - "Cannot convert value of type 'UITouch' to expected argument type 'CGPoint'  "

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to TheCodeComposer, I found the solution:

```
var targetNode: SKNode!

  override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */
        let touch: UITouch = touches.first as UITouch!
        touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
        targetNode = self.nodeAtPoint(touchLocation)
        objectTouched(touch.locationInNode(self))
    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch: UITouch = touches.first as UITouch!
        let newTouchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
//        let targetNode = self.nodeAtPoint(touchLocation)
        if targetNode.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask != PhysicsCategory.Ball {
        targetNode.runAction(SKAction.moveBy(CGVector(point: newTouchLocation - touchLocation), duration: 0.0))
        touchLocation = newTouchLocation
        }
    }
```

I only define

targetNode

once and then continue to use it instead of redefining it in touchesMoved: